# Weird arithmetic with datetimes and relativedelta

Tags: python, datetime, python-dateutil, relativedelta

Is it safe to multiply [`relativedelta`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-ba5ffd4df8111d1b83fc194b97ebecf837add454) objects?  I'm seeing some weird and inconsistent behaviour, and can't find it documented what sorts of arithmetic are supported by this class (if any)

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
>>> datetime.now() + relativedelta(days=2)
datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 30, 12, 24, 59, 173941)
>>> datetime.now() + relativedelta(days=1) * 2
# TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
```

On the other hand:

```
>>> relativedelta(days=2) == relativedelta(days=1) * 2
True
```

Full traceback (with `python` 2.7.5 and `dateutil` 1.5):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dateutil/relativedelta.py", line 261, in __radd__
    day = min(calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1],
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/calendar.py", line 121, in monthrange
    day1 = weekday(year, month, 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/calendar.py", line 113, in weekday
    return datetime.date(year, month, day).weekday()
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
```

Comment: I don't get such a `TypeError`. I get `datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 30, 12, 45, 2, 181770)` instead. What version of `python-dateutil` have you got installed? I used Python 2.7 and `python-dateutil` 2.2.

Comment: As for *is it safe to multiply*: yes, the type specifically implements both `__mul__` and `__rmul__` methods for this use-case. But I cannot reproduce your problem at all.

Comment: I can reproduce, using Python 2.7.5+. The exceptions seems to occur when you try to add a `relativedelta` that is the result of a multiplication, even when you do `* 1`

Comment: @tobias_k: I still can't. Care to share an example session? The full traceback even would be of some use.

Comment: @tobias_k: the source code of `__mul__` turns the other argument into a float, multiplies the relative components and turns the results back into integers. I don't see how that could lead to a `relativedelta()` instance that bombs out this way. A full traceback would at least help me trace back to a scenario where the error might occur, but that's sadly missing from this post. Hence my VtC as lacking info.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I just checked the types of the various fields of the `relativedelta` object. Before, they are all `int`, but after the multiplication, they are all `float`. Seems this is a problem with Python 2.7.x that was fixed in later versions.

Comment: @tobias_k: I'd say it's a problem with the version of `dateutil` then, because the version I have installed (2.2, latest), clearly uses `int()` for all values.

Comment: @tobias_k: see http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~dateutil/dateutil/trunk/view/head:/dateutil/relativedelta.py#L367, and more importantly [this revision](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~dateutil/dateutil/trunk/revision/116); looks like you (and wim perhaps) have an outdated version?

Comment: `dateutil` 1.5 in my case. See edit to the question.

Comment: It was indeed `dateutil` v1.5, I should have included that in my original post - thanks for the edit @tobias_k !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've run into a [known bug in `relativedelta`'s handling of multiplication](https://bugs.launchpad.net/dateutil/+bug/737099), since fixed. It only affects Python 2.7 or newer (call signatures of certain functions were tightened).

Upgrade your `python-dateutils` package to version 2.1 or newer.

Don't be put off by the 2.0-is-Python-3-only misinformation on the project documentation; 2.1 and 2.2 are Python 2 and 3 cross-compatible.